# Criar projeto angular sem usar o angular-cli

Tags: angular

Boa noite, prezados.
Alguém pode me dar instruções (ou links para artigos) sobre como criar um projeto em angular 4 do zero, sem usar o angular-cli?

Sou iniciante na linguagem e preciso aprender a criar uma aplicação sem o -cli.

Obrigado.

Comment: se eu entendi basicamente, algo muito parece seria algo assim https://mgechev.github.io/angular-seed/

Comment: por que sem o cli? E a forma correta de acordo com a documentação de como criar um projeto.

Comment: Não é só criar manualmente cada arquivo?

Comment: o recomendado e criar com angular cli conforme @AndersonCarlosWoss disse, porem existem projetos sem o angular cli que ao meu ver nao e recomendado para quem estar iniciado

Comment: Exatamente isso, @MarceloBatista! Muito obrigado! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar este exemplo [angular seed](https://mgechev.github.io/angular-seed/) para implementar as configurações, porém o mais sensato e avaliar se realmente vale a pena todo esse esforço (ou se é apenas por curiosidade), e se caso seja um projeto pequeno, o recomendado e utiliza o angular cli mesmo como mencionado nos comentários.

Para rodar o projeto angular seed e necessário essas configurações:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed.git
$ cd angular-seed

# install the project's dependencies
$ npm install
# fast install (via Yarn, https://yarnpkg.com)
$ yarn install  # or yarn

# watches your files and uses livereload by default
$ npm start
# api document for the app
# npm run build.docs

# generate api documentation
$ npm run compodoc
$ npm run serve.compodoc


# to start deving with livereload site and coverage as well as continuous testing
$ npm run start.deving

# dev build
$ npm run build.dev
# prod build
$ npm run build.prod

# dev build of multiple applications (by default the value of --app is "app")
$ npm start -- --app baz
$ npm start -- --app foo
$ npm start -- --app bar
```